# В работе приложения произошел сбой(unfortunately has stopped). Как решить проблему?

Tags: android, android-sdk

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{star.amv.zeroamv/star.amv.zeroamv.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at star.amv.zeroamv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6698)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Код

---

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import star.amv.zeroamv.Models.User;

import static star.amv.zeroamv.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;

    RelativeLayout  root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        btnSignIn=findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnRegister=findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        root = findViewById(R.id.root_element);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRegisterWindow();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showRegisterWindow() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Зарегистрироваться");
        dialog.setMessage("Введите все данные для регистрации");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View register_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registar_window, null);
        dialog.setView(register_window);

        final MaterialEditText email = register_window.findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        final MaterialEditText pass = register_window.findViewById(R.id.passField);
        final MaterialEditText name = register_window.findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        final MaterialEditText phone = register_window.findViewById(R.id.phoneField);

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Отменить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Введите вашу почту", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Введите ваше имя", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Введите ваш тедефон", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (pass.getText().toString().length() < 5) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Введите пароль, которое более 5 символов", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                // Регистрация пользователя
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                User user = new User();
                                user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                                user.setEmail(name.getText().toString());
                                user.setEmail(pass.getText().toString());
                                user.setEmail(phone.getText().toString());

                                users.child(user.getEmail())
                                        .setValue(user)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                Snackbar.make(root, "Пользователь добавлен!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });
            }

        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fon4"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_element"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ranga_bold"
        android:text="@string/text_bottom"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="341dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bntRegister"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_register"
            android:text="@string/bntRegister"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bntSignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_sign_in"
            android:text="@string/btnSignIn"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки из LogCat

Comment: готова, надеюсь скинул то что нужно, так как я новичок

Comment: Покажите код MainActivity, пожалуйста

Comment: код MainActivity.java прикрепил

Comment: `Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;` замените на `View btnSignIn, btnRegister;`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Заменил, нужно что то еще заменять?

Comment: Вроде, нет. Если не помогло - приложите тогда разметку еще)

Comment: разметки вроде бы нужное добавил. Activity_main.xml надо прикреплять для решения проблемы?

Comment: Только activity_main.xml и была нужна) Остальное проблемы не касается точно

Comment: `id`, по которому вы ищете кнопку, назначен контейнеру.

Comment: activity_main.xml прикрепил.

Comment: У Вас НЕуникальные id в разметке.. я, честно говоря, вообще не понимаю, чего Вы хотели добиться этими LinearLayout'ами уберите у них (LinearLayout) id

Comment: Ох, только сейчас заметил, id уникальные, но очень похожие)
поменяйте id у LinearLayout  и соответствующих Button местами

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог - отметьте его принятым, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте `activity_main.xml` таким образом:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fon4"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_element"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ranga_bold"
        android:text="@string/text_bottom"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bntSignIn"
        android:layout_width="341dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_register"
            android:text="@string/bntRegister"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bntRegister"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_sign_in"
            android:text="@string/btnSignIn"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Пояснение: у Вас `id`, по которым Вы искали кнопки были у элементов класса `LinearLayout` в разметке. Это и вызывало ошибку.

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
> ```

Comment: Да, и лучше давать идентификаторам осмысленные имена, чтобы не было таких недоразумений. Например, неплохо задавать префикс, обозначающий тип элемента. То есть `btnSignIn` - кнопка, `llSignIn` - её контейнер. И всё - никакой путаницы.